# Undo a new point while digitising?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

How to undo a point while digitizing with QGIS 2.18? I am digitizing polygon features.

Answer (score 1):

`Delete` gets rid of the latest point you set, when still in digitizing mode. `Backspace` is another option. Or you can move the point around.